# Symfony2 stack trace is not always displayed

Tags: debugging, symfony, vagrant, stack-trace

I'm developping using Symfony2 in a Ubuntu Server Vagrant Box.
There is no shared folders (due to weak performance), instead I configured my IDE to automaticaly send the modified files to the box by SSH.

My problem is, when I access a page which contain an error, sometimes the stack trace shows up, sometimes not, instead an Internal Server Error (error 500) occurs.

The app is still debuggable through the Symfony log but it's not as simple and comprehensive
as the stack trace...

It seems not to have correlation between the error type (twig, database, code...) and the display or not of the stack trace.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but speaking about your performance issues: There are at least two tweaks you should consider when using symfony and vagrant together: First, your symfony cache and log folders shouldn't reside inside your shared folder, this really kills performance. Inside your app/kernel.php override the `getCacheDir()` and `getLogDir()` methods so they return a path that is not part of the shared folder. And second, if you are on linux or mac, you should consider using nfs instead of VirtualBox guest additions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did use nfs and had my cache/log files in a RAM disk of the Vagrant Box. Despite of this, the performances were still not good. Furthermore, my IDE uses the cache files for the intellisense (PHPStorm W/ the Symfony plugin), so I need them localy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more inquisitions, it seems that xdebug is causing the problems. After disabling it, the stack trace is working again everytime.